# recursive searching with pathlib - python

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

Say I have these files

```
/home/user/one/two/abc.txt
/home/user/one/three/def.txt
/home/user/one/four/ghi.txt
```

I'm trying to find `ghi.txt` recursively using the `pathlib` module. I tried:

```
p = '/home/user/'
f = Path(p).rglob(*i.txt)
```

but the only way I can get the filename is by using a list comprehension:

```
file = [str(i) for i in f]
```

which actually only works once. Re-running the command above returns an empty list.

I decided to learn `pathlib` because apparently it's what is recommended by the community, but isn't:

```
file = glob.glob(os.path.join(p,'**/*i.txt'),recursive=True)
```

much more straightforward?

Comment: So apparently you have found two ways to solve your problem of which you prefer one. What is your question?

Comment: It only works once presumably because `rglob()` returns a generator which gets exhausted by your comprehension.   `f = tuple(Path(p).rglob(*i.txt))` would let you loop over it multiple times if you need to do that for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You already have a solution.

Not sure if I read the requirements correctly but I have posted the answer with the following assumptions.

- PathListPrefix is the starting path beneath which you want to search
  all files. In your case it might be '/home/user'
- FileName is the name of the file that you are looking for. In your case it is 'ghi.txt'
- You are not expecting more than one match.
- **Something other than pathlib modules has to be tried.**

As far as straightforward solution is concerned I am not sure about that either. However the below solution is what I could think of using os module.

```py
import os
PathListPrefix = '/home/user/'
FileName = 'ghi.txt'

def Search(StartingPath, FileNameToSearch):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(StartingPath)
    FileName = os.path.split(root)[1]
    if FileName+ext == FileNameToSearch:
        return True
    return False

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PathListPrefix):
    Path = root
    for eachfile in files:
        SearchPath = os.path.join(Path,eachfile)
        Found = Search(SearchPath, FileName)
        if Found:
            print(Path, FileName)
            break
```

The code is definitely having many many more lines than yours. So it is not as compact as yours.